# Root CA Certificate message appeared even though installed in localhost and configured in browser

Tags: jmeter

I am using Apache `apache-jmeter-3.2` I am facing the issue regarding Root Ca certificate. As I have successfully installed certificate Using Consol and Installed certificate under as described in the figure . I tried it couple of time but every time got the RootCa Certificate message. Here are two image illustrate the problem.

[image: Trusted Authority Path]

[image: Jmeter Root Ca Certificate Messgge]

Answer (score 0):

The root CA certificate message is just informational, it does not consider wether you installed it or not.

So you can safely ignore this.